# Cropping an image stored locally

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8

I'm kind of a greenhorn to Windows Phone development and I've been looking for a way in order to crop an image already built into the project (Maybe even from the camera some day), but every package I've found has either had a fuss with Visual Studio, or throws argument exceptions. So I've decided that I will make my own function to do so.

However, I have not the slightest idea where to start. I'm pretty sure WriteableBitmap has something to do with it, and something to do with the following code:

```
Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/PhoneApp3;component/Assets/Flowers/Daff.jpg"));
```

So how would one start out with getting the pixel data or creating a new image and apply pixel data. And finally how would one save the result and reference it through the UI's image elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) to crop images on Windows Phone. The way you solution will have to work is to manipulate the WritableBitmap.Pixels property. You first load in an image, change the Pixels property and transform the raw pixels into a saved image format like JPG or PNG. That's a lot of work so lucky for you WriteableBitmapEx does that for you.

First, install [WritebleBitmapEx from NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/WriteableBitmapEx):

> Install-Package WriteableBitmapEx

Then you can load any image, crop it and save back to the MediaLibrary. Here's for example how to load a file from the app's XAP, crop to top-left 25% of the image and save to the "Saved Pictures" WP7/8 album.

```cs
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(0, 0).FromContent("Assets/ApplicationIcon.png");
    var croppedBmp = bmp.Crop(0, 0, bmp.PixelWidth/2, bmp.PixelHeight/2);
    croppedBmp.SaveToMediaLibrary("myImage.jpg");
}
```

When we run this code we can see the new cropped image:

[image: Cropped image]

Comment: Wow. You are a wonderful person, it works exactly as demonstrated. Every other package I've downloaded had seemed to be incompatible with 8.0, I don't know how this one didn't show up in the results. Thank you! So how would I go about saving the image to the app's storage or applying it as a source to image element in the XAML?

Comment: What you have is a normal Silverlight/XAML/WP7 WriteableBitmap. Google is your friend. For storing local files use IsoStore, open up a IsolatedStorageFileStream and save to it using WriteableBitmap.SaveJpeg. For showing WriteableBitmaps just set an Image.Source property to the WriteableBitmap.

Comment: Thanks again, everytime I had tried to change the source of an image element I had encountered errors (in hindsight, it was probably improper URI formatting) and had actually came up with a hackish way to do it by having the images as collapsed elements and referenced their sources. Still haven't gotten quite used to the language. Thanks for everything man.

Answer (score 1):

I recently needed to do this and didn't want to use an external lib. Microsoft provide a good example on MSDN on how to do it (and is also very good at not causing memory leaks!)

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Photos-Sample-a38a2c8e

Cheers,
Will